# Opening program by double-clicking associated file, can't get filename!

Tags: c#

I have a program that has a file type associated with it (*.cqd). When the user double clicks a .cqd file, it opens up my program just fine, but I can't for the life of me get the name/path of the file used to open the program.

I've tried the following code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach (string s in args)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("MAIN: " + s);
    }
}
```

Which only gives me the path of the program itself.

I've also tried:

```
foreach (string arg in Environment.GetCommandLineArgs())
{
     MessageBox.Show(arg);
}
```

Which has the same effect. I'm having a hard time finding information on the topic because my searches give me "How do I open a file with it's associated program?" rather than the problem I'm having. Any help I can get would be appreciated.

**NINJA EDIT:** This is not a WPF project. Sorry I wasn't specific on that. I also fixed a quick typo.

**FOUND THE PROBLEM!**
When I publish the application, it publishes to a .application file. I went into the project's /bin/release/ folder and found the .exe file. When I drag a file onto the .exe, it properly passes the path into the arguments. Guess I need to read up more on why this is, and if I can get the .application file to work with arguments, seeing as how it has the auto-update of ClickOnce in it.

Thank you all for your help! If there's anything I need to do to close this thread, please let me know.

Comment: Do you mean `MessageBox.Show("MAIN: " + s);` in your first code section?

Comment: Using `args` would display "MAIN: System.String[]".

Comment: Fixed that, now for some reason it's not displaying anything in the Main() function and only showing a messagebox in the Environment.GetCommandLineArgs() code in Form_Load()

Comment: You should post your text after "found the problem" as an answer and then mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you meant:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     foreach (string s in args)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("MAIN: " + s);
     }
 }
```

Comment: D'oh. You're right, I did mean that. I'm still getting the same results though. I just tried adding a simple messagebox in Main() and, strangely, it only appears when the application is closing! I'm sorry if I'm missing something very obvious, but that doesn't make sense to me!

Comment: Yeah, something about this didn't smell right to me. I was trying to figure out why the second version wouldn't work, and I figured something else must be going on. I think @Jordaan Mylonas might be onto the real problem. This was probably just a typo in creating the question, as @MusiGenesis hints at.

Comment: Nevermind. I fixed the problem where that messagebox was only appearing when the form was unloading. I accidentally placed it after the Application.Run(new frmMain()); line. Sorry about that.

Comment: @MTBPatriot - You should associate your program with a batch file that calls `"whatever.exe" "%1"` and see if that does the trick.

Answer (score 4):

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments.ActivationData[0]
```

Works as well for ClickOnce activations

Answer (score 1):

[This blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avip/archive/2008/10/27/wpf-supporting-command-line-arguments-and-file-extensions.aspx) details your exact problem, and the solution.

But, in short, it's not stored in args, it's stored in:

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments.ActivationData[0]

(**This is all assuming you're using WPF**)

Comment: I am not using WPF, actually. I'm sorry I didn't specify that earlier.

Comment: Well, give it a shot anyway, see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

In App.xaml.cs

```
 protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Args != null && e.Args.Length > 0)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("dgda");
            //DirectOpenPath = e.Args[0].ToString();
            this.Properties["ArbitraryArgName"] = e.Args[0];
        }
        base.OnStartup(e);
    }
```

In MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
InitializeComponent();

        if (Application.Current.Properties["ArbitraryArgName"] != null)
        {

            string fname = Application.Current.Properties["ArbitraryArgName"].ToString();

            // Act on the file...
        }
```

Comment: Very nice and easy solution, helped me in my current program.